# How many Executors to use?

Tags: netty

The netty proxy example uses a single `Executors.newCachedThreadPool` for the `bossExecutor` and `workerExecutor` of both the server and client nio socket factories.
Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

Recap: *boss threads* are used to accept connections while *worker threads* do the actual work of processing incoming/outgoing buffers from channels.

Boss threads aren't typically very busy. Moreover netty needs only one thread per port, not really the whole pool. But you might decide e.g. to have one thread pool with one thread to server 10 ports. All ports will share and compete over the same single boss thread.

Back to your question: is it a good idea to have the same pool for boss and worker threads? It's not terrible, you make your design and maintenance a bit simpler. However there is a risk of accepting new connections with delay since all threads in the pool might be occupied by workers and no thread is left for boss. Don't think it's a big issue.